# Symmetric group acting on the set of boolean functions

Tags: finite-groups, group-actions, symmetric-groups, boolean-algebras

Let $S_n$ act on the set of boolean functions of size $n$ in the following way:

If $f$ is a boolean function and $\alpha \in S_n$, then $g=\alpha f$ and $g(x)=f(\alpha(x))$ where $x$ is boolean vector of size $n$;

Let $p$ be the number of orbits. Since each orbit can have no more than $n!$ elements it is obvious that $p\ge\frac{2^{2^n}}{n!}$.

I am interested in an upper bound of $p$. Do you know any related results?

Comment: Why do you have $2^{2^n}$ and not just $2^n$ in the approximation? In any case, it really seems that this is the same as the action of $S_n$ on subsets of $\{1,\ldots, n\}$, and the number of orbits is just $n+1$.

Comment: $2^{2^n}$ is the number of boolean functions of $n$ arguments. The group acts on that set.

Comment: So you mean "boolean functions on boolean functions on $n$ elements"?

Comment: I think Ashot means "Boolean functions in n variables". Such a thing, $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, accepts inputs $x_i\in \{0,1\}$ and produces an output in $\{0,1\}$. That is, it is a function from $\{0,1\}^n$ to $\{0,1\}$. There are $2^{2^n}$ such things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of orbits of a two-cycle $\sigma$ acting on subsets of
$\{1,\dots,n\}$ is $3\cdot 2^{n-2}$. If follows that the number of orbits of
$\sigma$ acting on boolean functions is $2^{2^{n-1}}\cdot 3^{2^{n-2}}$.
By the Cauchy-Frobenius lemma
(a.k.a. Burnside's lemma), it is then easy to see that
  $$ p =\frac{1}{n!}\left( 2^{2^n}+\binom n2 2^{2^{n-1}}\cdot 3^{2^{n-2}}
         + o\left(2^{2^{n-1}}\cdot 3^{2^{n-2}}\right)\right). $$
Thus for instance for all $\varepsilon>0$ and sufficiently large $n$
(depending on $\varepsilon$), we have
  $$ p<\frac{1}{n!}\left( 2^{2^n}+(1+\varepsilon)\binom n2 2^{2^{n-1}}\cdot 3^{2^{n-2}} \right). $$

Comment: One question. $\binom n2 2^{2^{n-1}}\cdot 3^{2^{n-2}}$ is number of orbits when a single two-cycle acts on the set of boolean functions, right?
By Cauchy-Frobenius lemma we should add number of functions that a group element leaves unchanged. I am missing something?